# How to aggregate (sum) in Apache Cassandra?

Tags: cassandra

I have table with milions of records so I need to grouping and sum values based on a query.

I know cassandra does not supports, so do I need to bring the milions of rows to memory and compute it in client side (in the case in Java) ?

Comment: Have you looked into using MapReduce for this?

Answer (score 1):

One option worth looking into is the [spark-cassandra-connector](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector).  There is a [simple tutorial](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/0_quick_start.md) you can go through that demonstrates how to do a 'count' and 'sum' from a cassandra table:

```scala
val rdd = sc.cassandraTable("test", "kv")
println(rdd.count)
println(rdd.map(_.getInt("value")).sum)
```

While the library is written in scala, there is a [java API](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/7_java_api.md) you can use as well. Additionally, you do not need to set up a spark cluster to get this working as you can use spark embedded in your client without any additional configuration.  As your needs grow you may want to consider setting up some spark workers though.

Answer (score 1):

May want to consider keeping a counter that you increment when adding entries to have the sum precomputed.

```
CREATE TABLE blargs_sum (
  sum counter,
  blarg varchar,
  PRIMARY KEY (blarg)
);

----

UPDATE blargs_sum SET sum = sum + 1 WHERE blarg='Rafael';
```

Another option is to do it with a light weight transaction with when inserting, perhaps even with a static column. But this would mean you would get a per partition total, not a global one. Can find example here: http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/cql-in-2-0-6

```
  BEGIN BATCH
    UPDATE bills SET balance = -208 WHERE user='user1' IF balance = -8;
    INSERT INTO bills (user, expense_id, amount, description, paid)
             VALUES ('user1', 2, 200, 'hotel room', false);
  APPLY BATCH;
```

Comment: Will this update work avoiding race condition? When a record is added, an hourly aggregate and a day aggregate is increased, but this aggregate will be calculated in a concurrent/parallel requests.